# How to validate and redirect on fail in CreateView get

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to do some sanity checks in a CreateView get request and want to redirect user to a different URL in case the sanity checks fail. How can I achieve this?

For example:

```
class JobCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Job
    form_class = JobFormClass

    # This does not let me redirect on return since a dictionary return is expected and redirect is not acceptable
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        if not self.request.user.is_superuser:
            messages.add_message(
                 self.request,
                 messages.ERROR,
                 _("You are not authorized! Bugger off!")
            )

            return redirect("home")

        # The user is good to proceed
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

This gives me back the following error:

```
context must be a dict rather than HttpResponseRedirect.
```

I am using get_context_data because I don't know what to use to be honest. Feel free to suggest something better.
My use case in not really a super user check, that just felt like a better example

Answer (score 1):

First method call in instance of view is dispatch, so move your code to this method:

```
class JobCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Job
    form_class = JobFormClass

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            messages.add_message(
                 self.request,
                 messages.ERROR,
                 _("You are not authorized! Bugger off!")
            )
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return super(JobCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Or you can try user decorator:

```
@method_decorator(user_passes_test(lambda user: user.is_superuser), name='dispatch')
```

Comment: Thanks! That works! I also experimented with ```get``` and that seems to work as well as I expected. Which seems like the preferred option and why?

Comment: if your condition is involved with user than use decorator,  in another case you can create abstract class with specific condition in dispatch method